# Cooldowns in discord.py with on_message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I basically messed up. This is the first time I've ever tried a discord bot and I've done all my code in on_message with it checking the content of the message to see if it matches with the command name (example below). I've added a few commands, which are quite long, and I don't really want to rewrite it. Is there any way around this or do I have to rewrite it?

```
  if message.content.lower().startswith("!test"):  
    await message.channel.send(db[str(message.author.id)])
```

Simple example of what I'm doing, just a test command.

I have tried looking inside other questions but I either: don't want to do that or don't understand what people are saying.

Any help would be appreciated and since I'm new to discord.py; I might need it explained in bit easier terms please.

Comment: I would recommend rewriting personally, you can port to the correct setup with very little deviation from what you already have. The core code will be the exact same, just with a different setup. You'll regret putting it off.

Comment: You should upgrade from Discord.py to Pycord. Pycord is a maintained version of Discord.py.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
import asyncio
users_on_cooldown = [] # Consider renaming this if you are going to have multiple commands with cooldowns.
def on_message(msg):
    if msg.content.lower().startswith("!test") and not msg.author.id in users_on_cooldown:  
        await msg.channel.send(db[str(msg.author.id)])
        users_on_cooldown.append(msg.author.id)
        await asyncio.sleep(20) # time in seconds
        users_on_cooldown.remove(msg.author.id)
```

Since you said you are a beginner, please note that if you make another command with a separate cooldown, use another variable that `users_on_cooldown`, maybe something like `ban_cmd_cooldown` and `test_cmd_cooldown`.

<kbd>**How It Works**</kbd> When the command is used, the user is added to a list, and after a certain amount of seconds, they are removed. When the command is run, it is checked if the user is on the list.

<kbd>**Note:** When the bot is reset, cooldowns will be reset too.</kbd>

If you have any questions about this, feel free to ask in the comments below.

Comment: This sounds dumb but how come ```asyncio.sleep(20)``` comes out as unrecognised - is there any imports I need to add? As well, is this the same as time.sleep? If so, doesn't that stop all the code and means that no other commands can be used?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that you will need to import `asyncio`. And I forgot to await it. It wont block (stop code). See my edited answer. @Nobody

Answer (score -1):

Here how to use

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(db[str(message.author.id)])
```

`(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user)` means 1 msg per 60sec or a 60sec cooldown.

I would recommend you rewrite your bot. It may take some time but it'll be worth it.

Comment: discord.ext.commands no longer uses `client`. Consider using `bot.command` and `bot = commands.Bot()`.

Comment: Maybe add clarification on what `commands.BucketType.user` means.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I know what commands.BucketType.user means but I don't really understand two things: what ctx is and how is this called whenever a user types in a command? I'm sorry that this sounds dumb; I'm only a bit use to regular python without any libraries.

Comment: `ctx` is context